# Oracle connection failure to service with 'HA Events=True' in connection string

Tags: oracle

I'm assuming this is a configuration problem. Some background. I'm running a Windows 7 VM with VM Player. I've installed Oracle 11gR2 within the VM along with clients, Enterprise Manager, SQL Developer, and ODP.NET drivers (32 bit and 64 bit). I have no oracle experience before this project but I have followed a fairly detailed list of steps set up by someone who knows what they are talking about.

If I connect to a service via the ODP.NET driver (v4.112.1.2) with 'HA EVENTS=True' in the connection string it will not connect. If I remove the 'HA EVENTS=True' from the connection string it will connect. I've tested this with a small console app I created that simply opens a connection then tries to read from it and close. The error message returned is 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-24912: Listener thread failed. %s'. The internet is surprisingly devoid of information on that error code. The only solutions I could find is the listener needs to be restarted and reinstall Oracle. I'm able to connect via SQL Developer, SQL Plus, ODBC. Any thoughts on where I should look next?

Messages in the tnslsnr log look like so:

```
<msg time='2013-01-22T17:02:48.306-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr' type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='MACHINENAME' host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>22-JAN-2013 17:02:48 * (connect_data=(service_name=oradev1_a)(failover_mode=(type=select))(CID=(PROGRAM=c:\users\username\documents\visual?studio?2010\Projects\TestOdpNetConnect\TestOdpNetConnect\bin\Debug\TestOdpNetConnect.vshost.exe)(HOST=MACHINENAME)(USER=username))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=::1)(PORT=50915)) * establish * oradev1_a * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2013-01-22T17:02:48.364-08:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr' type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='MACHINENAME' host_addr='::1'>
 <txt>22-JAN-2013 17:02:48 * (connect_data=(service_name=oradev1_a)(failover_mode=(type=select))(CID=(PROGRAM=c:\users\username\documents\visual?studio?2010\Projects\TestOdpNetConnect\TestOdpNetConnect\bin\Debug\TestOdpNetConnect.vshost.exe)(HOST=MACHINENAME)(USER=username))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=::1)(PORT=50916)) * establish * oradev1_a * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

Note: A successful connection looks the same in this log.

'lsnrctl services' looks like so:

```
LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 23-JAN-2013 08:38:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "oradev1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oradev1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:178 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "oradev1XDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oradev1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: MACHINENAME, pid: 3916>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MachineName)(PORT=49297))
Service "oradev1_a" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oradev1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:178 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "oradev1_b" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oradev1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:178 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\oracle
```

TnsNames.ora:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORADEV1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oradev1)
    )
  )
```

Note: I've tried with 'HOST = MachineName' in Listener.ora and TnsNames.ora but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

ODP.NET log:

```
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (VERSION)  (4.112.2.0)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (DllPath : C:\Oracle\x64\11.2.0.1.2\bin)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (TraceFileName : C:\odplog\odpnet4.trc)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (TraceLevel : 63)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (TraceOption : 1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (CheckConStatus : 1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (UdtCacheSize : 4096)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (StatementCacheSize : 0)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (DynamicEnlist : 0)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (FetchSize : 131072)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (OCI_EVENTS : 0)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (StatementCacheWithUdts : 1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (MetadataPooling : 1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (DBNotificationPort : -1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (ThreadPoolMaxSize : -1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (DBNotificationRegInterval : 0)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (DemandOraclePermission : 0)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (SelfTuning : True)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (MaxStatementCacheSize : 100)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (AppEdition : )
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (MetaDataXml : )
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (RevertBatchUpdateErrorHandling : 0)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:751 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (FetchArrayPooling : 1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:752 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (PerformanceCounters : None)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:752 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (PSPE : 1)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:752 TID: 930  (REGISTRY) (ThreadPoolMaxSize : -1 [Original: 32767; Set: -1; Post-Set: 32767])
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:755 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::OracleConnection(2)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:46:819 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OracleConnection::OracleConnection(2)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:47:692 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OracleCommand::OracleCommand(3)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:47:692 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OracleCommand::OracleCommand(3)
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:227 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OracleConnection::Open()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:227 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:227 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=399
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:294 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:294 TID: 930  (HA)    OpsConOpen(): OciEvents=0 Line=1773
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:331 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:331 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3320 (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:331 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsErrAllocCtx(): (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:331 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=197 (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:331 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConOpen(): RetCode=0 Line=2353 (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:337 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConInitSubscrEnv()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:338 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConInitSubscrEnv(): RetCode=0 Line=3597
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:341 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConAllocValCtx()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:341 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConAllocValCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=399
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:343 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConRegisterCallbacks()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:343 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConOpen()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:373 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConAddRef(): (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:373 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConAddRef(): RefCount=1 RetCode=0 Line=3320 (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:373 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsErrAllocCtx(): (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:373 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsErrAllocCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=197 (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:373 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConOpen(): RetCode=0 Line=2353 (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:500 TID: 930  (HA)    CreateSubscription(): RetCode=-1 Line=3723
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:500 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConRegisterCallbacks(): RetCode=-1 Line=3836
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:500 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:503 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:503 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsErrFreeCtx()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:503 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsErrFreeCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=224
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:503 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=0 RetCode=0 Line=3496 (0)=0
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:503 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1293 (20fb880)=34584704
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:503 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:503 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1371
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:510 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConClose(): (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:513 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConRelRef(): (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:513 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsErrFreeCtx()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:513 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsErrFreeCtx(): RetCode=0 Line=224
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:516 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConRelRef(): RefCount=0 RetCode=0 Line=3496 (0)=0
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:517 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConClose(): RetCode=0 Line=1293 (20fb600)=34584064
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:520 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsConDispose(): (0)=0
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:520 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsConDispose(): RetCode=0 Line=1371
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:534 TID: 930  (ENTRY) OpsErrGetOraMesg()
TIME:2013/01/22-17:02:48:534 TID: 930  (EXIT)  OpsErrGetOraMesg(): RetCode=0 Line=310
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem with not having the VM connected to a network and domain.

Here's what I did:

1. Wiped Oracle clean off the VM as best I could.
2. Installed a [loopback adapter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/reqs.htm#BABGCEAI).
3. Assigned the VM a fake domain name.
4. Set the ORACLE_HOSTNAME environment variable.
5. Reinstalled oracle according to the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24186/install.htm) and document I had.

After all of this I had a working Oracle install with high availability events working. Naturally these were not the first steps I tried so there might be some other contributing factor I missed in this list.